# Identifying the subject of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Please could you tell me the subject of the sentence below? Is it 'He' or 'she'? Thanks.

> He believes she went to London.

Comment: what is the verb? If you think it is *believes*, than the subject is *he*. If you think it is *went*, then what do you think *believes* is?

Comment: This is a complex sentence. There are two clauses because there are two main verbs (_believes_ and _went_). Each clause has a subject. The subject of _believes_ is _he_; the subject of _went_ is _she_. Therefore there is no single subject here; there are two subjects, one for each clause.

Comment: "He" is the subject, because he's doing the believing.  What he believes is that she went to London.

Answer (score 6):

> He believes she went to London.

**The sentence**

The Original Poster's question is what is the Subject of this *sentence*. The constituents of the sentence are:

- Subject, *he*; Predicator (verb), *believes*; Complement, *she went to London*

To test what the Subject is here we can put a question tag on the question, and see which word occurs in the tag:

- He believes she went to London, doesn't **he**?

This shows *he* to be the Subject, as it's the word that occurs in the tag. Just to be sure, we could also change the sentence into a yes/no question, and see which word inverts (changes places) with the auxiliary verb:

- Does he believe she went to London?

Again, this confirms *he* as the Subject - it's *he* which has inverted with auxiliary verb *Do*.

**The function of *she***

What then is the function of *she*? Well, the Complement of  *believe* is the subordinate finite clause *she went to London*. Finite (declarative, content) clauses have the same structure as normal sentences. They are subordinate clauses instead of real sentences when they play some special function inside a larger sentence. The subordinate clause here is:

- she went to London.

If we extract the clause from the larger sentence, we can do some tests to see what function *she* has within this clause. So, for example we can pretend it's a proper sentence and see what occurs if we stick a question tag on the end:

- she went to London, didn't **she**?

This seems to show that *she* is the Subject of the clause. We can pretend it's a full sentence and turn it into a yes/no question:

- Did she go to London?

This gives us further confirmation that *she* is the Subject, as we can see subject auxiliary inversion with *she* and *did*.

**The Original Poster's question**

So in terms of what is the subject of the sentence, the answer is *he*. In terms of what function or job is *she* playing in the sentence, it's the subject of the subordinate clause *she went to London*.

Answer (score 1):

It may help your understanding to add the implicit "that":

> He believes that she went to London.

The basic meaning of the sentence is

> He believes X

From which it should be clear that "he" is the subject.  X is the object - the thing which he believes.  What does he believe? That she went to London.

In your sentence, "she went to London" (or "that she went to London") is a "noun clause" - a subordinate clause serving as a noun.  Unlike many subordinate clauses, this one could stand alone as a full, grammatically correct sentence, which is probably the cause of your confusion.  If it *were* standing alone, "she" would be the subject.  Here, in contrast, "she went to London" is the object.

Comment: Is not the term 'subject' also applied to all finite clauses?

Answer (score 0):

He believes she went to London.

? believes ?

Someone believes something. "He" is the subject  and the clause 
"she went to London" the object.

In the clause "she went to London" "she is the subject, "went" the verbal sentence part and "to London" the adverbial sentence part.

The object of a verb can be

1 a noun/noun group

2 a pronoun replacing the noun/noun group

3 a whole sentence (in English grammars called clause when it is part of another sentence)

To illustrate the development of such "object-sentences/object-clauses"
we may assume the following steps:

1 He believes something.

2"What?

3 She went to London.

And 1 to 3 evolved to: He believes she went to London.

With "that" this illustration becomes even simpler:

He believes that: She went to London.

Please take this as an illustration intended to convey an idea of how such
sentence structures come into being.

It would be another matter to show the historical process of development
with genuine example sentences in old languages. And I think it would be quite 
a task till you will find appropriate sentence material. But a good example is Italian perché which is the question word why or literally what for. And  it can be the subordinating conjunction because:

Non puo venire perché è malato.

Word for word translation, no proprer English:

"Not he-can come - why?/because - he-is ill.

In proper English:

He can't come because he is ill.